# Update data in MSACCESS

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access, oledbcommand

I have the following code to update the student record.
It is working without any error or exception but it is not updating the record.

I do not understand why this is happening.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String query = "Update Student Set StdName=@Name , Marks=@Marks where RollNo=@RollNo";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RollNo", OleDbType.VarChar, 10);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar, 10);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Marks", OleDbType.Integer);

        cmd.Parameters["@RollNo"].Value = txtRollNo.Text;
        cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = txtName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters["@Marks"].Value = Convert.ToInt16(txtMarks.Text);

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Update Successfully");
            ClearFields();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

It shows the message "Record Update Successfully" but does not update the record.
When i show all records in datagrid view.

Comment: WPF is a UI technology. It has **absolutely NOTHING** to do with database operations of any kind.

Comment: If your query is executing without errors then the query is valid, however this does not mean that it is correct for your purpose. I suggest you open SQL Studio and test the SQL query you are trying to execute in that to make sure it's updating the records how you want. THEN move that query to your code.

Answer (score 3):

When using OLEDB parameters are purely positional - it ignores the names you've given the parameters and assigns the first value to the first parameter, the second to the second and so on.

So I believe to make the above work you'd need to change the order in which you create the parameters to reflect the order in which you use the parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar, 10);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Marks", OleDbType.Integer);    
cmd.Parameters.Add("@RollNo", OleDbType.VarChar, 10);
```

Hopefully that will work!

Comment: Can I have my tick please (-: